# R 2.15.2 sqlFetch() on Win7 OS is terminating the R session

Tags: r, finder-sql

R 2.15.2 `sqlFetch()` on Win7 OS is terminating the R session.
However, `sqlQuery()` function returns the values properly with termination.
Please, help me resolving the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This will be much easier to solve if you provide a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

There are many places that this could be going wrong, so you need to try and isolate the problem.

Are you passing the same SQL to `sqlFetch` as you are to `sqlQuery`?
Is the connection handle (from `odbcConnect`) the same?
Can you retrieve just one row? (Pass `max = 1` to `sqlFetch`?)
Do you have the correct permissions on your database?
Can you retrieve data from a local instance of the database?